# Swapping images with Javascript/Dom

Tags: javascript, dom

this is my second Javascript/Dom query this evening but this is really quite a different query and thus probably deserves a new topic. My ultimate goal is to create a sliding puzzle game with a 4 x 4 grid. With some help in the other thread I have got the script to show the images in a 4 x 4 grid in a random order, with a shuffle button that again randomizes the images. The images are name image00, 01, 02, 03, 10, 11 etc up to 33 - 33 is my blank image.

Now I want to add commands that say if this image is clicked and it is next to the blank tile (image 33) then swap with the blank image. The only problem is, that I have no idea where to begin. My code so far is below. From what I've seen it would be something along the lines of using the images ID's but I am very new to javascript and haven't been able to find much that has helped me so far. Any help is really appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Shuffle</title>
</head>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

var Pics = [];
var Top = 16;

Pics = new Array();


for(i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
  document.write("<img>");
  if ((i+1)%4 == 0) {
    document.write("<br>");
  }
}

function ShuffleArray(a) {
  var n = a.length;
  for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var tmp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = tmp;
  }
}


function ViewerObj(Image, Pics, i) {
  this.Image = Image;
  this.Image.style.left = 800;
  this.Pics = Pics;
  this.Image.id = "ID" + i;
}

function Randomise() {
  var i;
  ShuffleArray(Pics);
  for(i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
    Viewers[i].Image.src = Pics[i];
    Viewers[i].Image.style.left = 200;
  }
}



Viewers = new Array();
var i;

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
 Pics[j + 4*i] = "images/Tree" + (i) + (j) + ".jpg";  
}
}

for(i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
  document.images[i].src = Pics[i];
  document.images[i].style.left = 300;
  Viewers[i] = new ViewerObj(document.images[i], Pics, i);
}


//-->​
</script>
<h1>Shuffle</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Shuffle" onClick="Randomise();"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for jQuery. It will make many things easier.

Comment: It's part of a project where I can't use libraries - really would appreciate some help with this as it's a major stumbling block!

Comment: This doesnt work for me, but mybe you get some hints: http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/image_puzzle/image_puzzle.html

Comment: Looks a little too complicated - I'm trying to learn this so as simple as possible is what I need.

Comment: Maybe you should go on with the swap images function? Something like image onlick='swap()' or image.onclick = function(){ swapMe() };